# Read 32-bit integer from binary file in C++?

Tags: c++, file, fstream

My binary file looks like this.

```
00000000: 0000 0803 0000 ea60 0000 001c 0000 001c
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

left column is address.

I just tried to read `0000 0803`(=2051) as follows

```
ifstream if;
if.open("file");
uint32_t a;
if >> a;
```

As expected...It did not work :-( 
`a` was just 0 after execution.
I tried `long, int, unsigned int, unsigned long`. All failed.

Why these are not working and how can I achieve the goal?

Comment: Did you check whether the file was opened correctly? What's the state of the stream after the read? (fail or bad state?)

Comment: remember about open mode - second argument to open (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode).

Comment: And you need to know what endianness was used when saving the file. Little-endian (e.g. Intel x86): Least significant byte on lowest address, Big-endian (e.g. the internet): Most significant byte on lowest address.

Comment: If you're reading the MNIST image dataset from LeCun on an Intel PC, then you'll need to reverse the byte order as @ErikAlapää mentioned.

Comment: @plhn just a side note: maybe `if` is not a valid name for your `ifstream` variable...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. Insuring you read the bytes you intend (no fewer, no more) from the stream.

   I'd recommend this syntax:

   `uint32_t a;`

   `inFILE.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&a), sizeof(a));`
2. Insure you're interpreting those bytes with the correct byte order.

   Q: If you're on a PC, your CPU is probably [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  Do you know if your data stream is also little-endian, or is it big endian?

   If the data is big-endian, I'd consider the standard networking functions to accomodate byte order: `ntohl()`, etc: http://www.retran.com/beej/htonsman.html

ALSO:

Follow Hcorg's and Daniel Jour's advice: don't forget about the "open mode" parameter, and don't forget to check for "file open" errors.

Comment: Actually, there is 3 issues: he needs to read the data hexadecimal as well, which is probably the biggest problem.

Comment: It would be better to explain some reasons about first issue.(=Why do you recommend `read` function, not input stream?)

Comment: why doesn't `>>` work? is this a documented behavior?

Comment: @zhangxaochen >> is looking for the ASCII representation of the numbers, to read 42 it expects to see 0x34, 0x32 in the stream '4' and '2', not 0x2a

Answer (score 5):

Open file in binary mode and then use `read()` method, something like:

```cpp
uint32_t a;
ifstream file ("file", ios::in | ios::binary);
if (file.is_open())
{
     file.read ((char*)&a, sizeof(a));
}
```

Comment: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'char_type *' (aka 'char *') with an rvalue of type 'int32_t *' (aka 'int *'). What about it?

Comment: @LRDPRDX What about "what"? Did you ask question about your case and provide an example? (in my snippet there is no conversion to char, as well as no initialization).

Comment: I just tried to compile your snippet. And there was the error I printed above.

Comment: @LRDPRDX I do not have the opportunity to check (has no c++ compiler for Android in Galaxy Note-3)... but it is the definitely issue of pointer type conversion. Try to add explicit conversion for `&a` : `file.read((char*)&a, sizeof(a));`

Comment: Implicitely I was saying about it.