# read 32 bit integer from binary file in c++

Tags: c#, c++, fstream

i'm trying to read a 32 bit integer from a binary file in c++. My goal is to obtain something similar to the c# BinaryReader.ReadInt32() method.  As [specified here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader.readint32?view=netframework-4.8), this c# method reads a 4 bytes signed integer. I have verified that my input file is little-endian, and the first 4 bytes read by the c# method are 0x0000001E (aka 30), which is correct, i double checked it using a binary editor.

I've already tried to follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066027/read-32-bit-integer-from-binary-file-in-c) but my code doesn't seem to work:

```
std::fstream _inputStream(fname.c_str(), std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in | std::ios::ate);

if (!_inputStream.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "Error opening the file\n" << fname << "\n" << std::endl;      
}

uint32_t a;
_inputStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a), sizeof(a));
```

I keep getting a = 0xCCCCCCCC, what am i missing?

thanks in advance

Comment: Remove: `std::ios::ate` - _"seek to the end of stream immediately after open"_ source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode

Comment: and what _inputStream.read returns?

Comment: @BiesiGrr True, i didn't see it sorry.

Comment: @RichardCritten THANKS! Damn dumb copy-paste... i was already tinkering with different data types...

Comment: @RichardCritter Please, answer to my question with your comment, so that i can select it as the answer! Thanks again.

Comment: You should not need `.c_str()`. Since C++11 there is a constructor taking a `std::string` directly, which `fname` probably is.